# how to make a high quality animated image with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want to make an animated gif from those .png image:

[image][image][image][image]

I do it with this command:

```
convert -layers OptimizePlus -delay 25x100 ps1-*.png -loop 0 ps1.gif
```

It made an animated gif successfully, however, the output has very low quality and  smaller than input images:

[image]

After some search, I got -quality

```
convert -layers OptimizePlus -delay 25x100 -quality 99 ps1-*.png -loop 0 ps1.gif
```

But it seems like imagemagick just ignore the parameter.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that your source PNGs have an alpha channel which is not supported by GIFs. So you have to [remove transparency](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#remove) from your source images first. Since you're dealing with multiple source images, you can't use the `-flatten` method. With newer ImageMagick versions the following should work:

```
convert -background white -alpha remove -layers OptimizePlus -delay 25x100 ps1-*.png -loop 0 ps1.gif
```

If your version of ImageMagick is older than 6.7.5, you can try:

```
convert -bordercolor white -border 0 -layers OptimizePlus -delay 25x100 ps1-*.png -loop 0 ps1.gif
```

I got the following result with the latter command:

[image: animation]

Comment: GIF does support transparency. The result GIF posted in the question is transparent.

Comment: @DreaminginCode But GIF only supports fully transparent pixels and no alpha channel. That's why you get the jagged edges.

Comment: But there are still plenty of transparent GIFs and a common way people achieve it is to actually only place the semi-transparent pixels on a white background, so that in most cases the edge does not seem to be aliased. There is a border matte option in Photoshop when exporting GIFs, but I haven't find a good way for imagemagick yet.